# Sorting an Array of custom objects by a dictionary included in the custom object: How?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nssortdescriptor

I have an array of custom objects. The objects includes a dictionary.
Something like this:

```
CustomDataModel *dataModel;

dataModel.NSString
dataModel.NSDictionary
dataModel.image
```

I'd like to sort by one of the objects in the dictionary:

```
dataModel.NSDictionary ObjectWithkey=@"Name"
```

The dataModel gets loaded into an NSArray. I now want to sort the by the @"Name" key in the dictionary. Is this something NSSortDescriptor can handle? Basic sort works fine, just haven't figured this one out  yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't completely clear to me, but you can try something like this on your NSArray:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedItems:(NSArray*)items;
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortNameDescriptor = 
                        [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                          initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:NO] 
                          autorelease];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = 
                        [[[NSArray alloc] 
                          initWithObjects:sortNameDescriptor, nil] 
                          autorelease];

    return [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I came up with as well, However, I wasn't sure it would work at first because of the NSDictionary. Anyways, Works like a charm! Thanks for the help and confirmation, Matt.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Sort an array which holds different dictionries - STRING BASED   - Declare it in the .h
    - (NSArray *)sortStringsBasedOnTheGivenField:(id)dictionaryKey arrayToSort:(NSMutableArray *)arrayToHoldTemp ascending:(BOOL)ascending {
        NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:dictionaryKey ascending:ascending selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] ;
        NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:nameDescriptor];
        [arrayToHoldTemp sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
        [nameDescriptor release];
        return arrayToHoldTemp;
    }
```

Usage:

```
self.mainArrayForData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self sortNumbersBasedOnTheGivenField:@"Name" arrayToSort:arrayWhichContainsYourDictionries ascending:YES]];
```

the above method is good for an array that holds dictionaries